# Trying to install 'Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.22-115126.vbox-extpack' with returning error

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, virtualbox

When I try to install the file `Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.1.22-115126.vbox-extpack`, downloaded from virtualbox.org, it returns this error message. I have only minor knowledge about Ubuntu and are not a very adept programmer, so could you please help me interpret this error message? **Do you know what I should do to fix this error/problem?**

[image]

I'm trying to enable the USB functionality in virtualbox, which is why I want to add the extension pack. If you need any translations (swedish words are included in the picture), just leave me a comment down below and I will give it.

Output of `dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii`.

[image]

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii`. Start comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema, please take a look at my question again - I have edited it.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text and apply code formatting instead.

Comment: @muru, I will do that in my next question. Thank you for telling me : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to install an extension pack for VirtualBox 5.1.22, and your installed version of Virtualbox is 4.3.36.

Either

- install the [correct extension pack for your version](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.36/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.36-105129a.vbox-extpack) or
- remove all traces of Virtualbox 4.3.36 and install the most current version of Virtualbox 5.1.22 and then the extension pack that you downloaded earlier.

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
  ```